# Wrapping the element and generating new file base on parameter in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file which i need to create multiple files on the basis of parameter value. While generating i found the data is moving in output along with remain in main file as well.

**INPUT XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
    <para style="CoverText10pt">Cover Title</para>
    <para style="CoverFormType">Cover Form Type</para>
    <para style="ExhibitHead">EXHIBIT 31.1</para>
    <para style="abc">EXHIBIT 31.1 para 1</para>
    <para style="bcz">EXHIBIT 31.1 para 2</para>
    <para style="ExhibitHead">EXHIBIT 31.2</para>
    <para style="klm">EXHIBIT 31.2 para 1</para>
    <para style="opq">EXHIBIT 31.2 para 2</para>
    <para style="aaa">EXHIBIT 31.2 para 3</para>
    <para style="ExhibitHead">Exhibit 32.2</para>
    <para style="MainHeading">Exhibit 32.2 para 1</para>
    <para style="aza">Exhibit 32.2 para 2</para>
    <para style="aza">Exhibit 32.2 para 3</para>
</document>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT HTML:** New Files are generating proper but remains the following siblings again remain in main output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Cover Title</p>
      <p>Cover Form Type</p>
      <p>EXHIBIT 31.1 para 1</p>
      <p>EXHIBIT 31.1 para 2</p>
      <p>EXHIBIT 31.2 para 1</p>
      <p>EXHIBIT 31.2 para 2</p>
      <p>EXHIBIT 31.2 para 3</p>
      <p>Exhibit 32.2 para 1</p>
      <p>Exhibit 32.2 para 2</p>
      <p>Exhibit 32.2 para 3</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT:** The content which are going in new Files should not appear in main output. (Ex: after para/@ExhibitHead should not comes in main output because i moved into another.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Cover Title</p>
      <p>Cover Form Type</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <html>
            <head><title>title</title></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:param name="ExhibitSplit" select="'yes'"/>

    <xsl:template match="para[@style='ExhibitHead' or @style='exhibithead']">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="lower-case($ExhibitSplit) = 'yes'">

                <xsl:variable name="file-name" select="normalize-space(.)"/>

                <xsl:result-document href="{concat($file-name,'.html')}">
                    <html>
                        <body>
                            <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node() 
                                except (
                                following-sibling::para[@style='ExhibitHead' or @style='exhibithead'],
                                following-sibling::para[@style='ExhibitHead' or @style='exhibithead']/following-sibling::*
                                )"/>

                        </body>
                    </html>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the grouping you want to perform is better done with `for-each-group group-starting-with` e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="document">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para[lower-case(@style) = 'exhibithead']">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="self::para[lower-case(@style) = 'exhibithead']">
                            <xsl:result-document href="{normalize-space()}.html">
                                <html>
                                    <body>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                    </body>
                                </html>
                            </xsl:result-document>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That will unconditionally split so you might want to wrap the `for-each-group` into an `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose/when` with your variable so that you only use it when the variable has the desired value. I am also not sure whether in the new file you need

```
                                    <body>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                    </body>
```

or

```
                                    <body>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ."/>
                                    </body>
```

it depends on whether the head element should be output as well or not.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I got the solution.

Comment: Actually the split information will come through outside parameter from user its depend on the requirement. If they required split then only ihave to split.